# Display DIV onclick and hide onclick with transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How can I show `#b1` when clicked on `#a1`, and show `#b2` when clicked on `#a2`? I need them to close as well (if you click, it will show and if you click again it will close). If you can add transition even better.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <ul class="head_dd">
        <li id="a1">INTERIOR</li>
        <li id="a2">EXTERIOR</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="bt1int" id="b1" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="bt1int" id="b2" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Comment: Using jQuery this is very beginner level stuff. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this would be to attach event listeners to each of the elements and then use the [`.fadeToggle()` method](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) to show/hide the corresponding element.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3hs3Lb20/)

```
$('#a1').on('click', function () {
    $('#b1').fadeToggle();
});
$('#a2').on('click', function () {
    $('#b2').fadeToggle();
});
```

Since this could get relatively redundant, you could simplify it to the following:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7L1db9zt/)

```
var mapping = {
    'a1': 'b1',
    'a2': 'b2'
}
$('.head_dd [id]').on('click', function () {
    $('#' + mapping[this.id]).fadeToggle();
});
```

#### Without jQuery:

You could also use plain JavaScript and CSS3 transitions:

```js
var mapping = {
    'a1': 'b1',
    'a2': 'b2'
}
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.head_dd [id]'), function (el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function () {
      document.getElementById(mapping[this.id]).classList.toggle('visible');
    });
});
```

```css
.bt1int {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
.visible {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <ul class="head_dd">
        <li id="a1">a1</li>
        <li id="a2">a2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="bt1int" id="b1">b1</div>
<div class="bt1int" id="b2">b2</div>
```

Comment: plus for the wonderful effort and great answer... and I had an answer! LOL

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

HTML code should put data on div content to differ between them.

```
<div class="wrap">
             <ul class="head_dd">
                <li id="a1">INTERIOR</li>
                <li id="a2">EXTERIOR</li>
            </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="bt1int" id="b1" style="display: none;">a</div>
 <div class="bt1int" id="b2" style="display: none;">b</div>
```

JS code(place this on head section or bottom of body)

```
<script>
$(function(){

  $('#a1').on('click',function(){
    $('#b2').hide();
    $('#b1').show();
  });
  $('#a2').on('click',function(){
    $('#b1').hide();
    $('#b2').show();
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach event listeners to to the elements.

```
var a1 = $('#a1');
var a2 = $('#a2');
var b1 = $('#b1');
var b2 = $('#b2');

a1.addEventListener('click', function(){
  b1.slideToggle(600);
});

a2.addEventListener('click', function(){
  b2.slideToggle(600);
});
```

or the alternate

```
$('#a1').on( 'click', function(){
  $('#b1').slideToggle(600);
});

$('#a2').on( 'click', function(){
  $('#b2').slideToggle(600);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add name attribute of each li as target div id

```
    <ul class="head_dd">
        <li id="a1" name="b1" >INTERIOR</li>
        <li id="a2" name="b2" >EXTERIOR</li>
    </ul>
```

then add following js

```
$(".head_dd li").click(function(e){
    var targetId = $(this).attr("name");
    if($("#"+targetId).is(':visible')){
        $("#"+targetId).hide(); 
    }else{
        $("#"+targetId).show();
    }
});
```